# Role of CN(CommonName) in Subject of UserCertifitcate

Tags: browser, client-certificates

When we use SSLConnection, we have to use certificate.
I think if it's server certificate, The CN(CommonName) inside subject have to be Server Domain.
While, if it's user certificate, The CN will be identity infomation(ex.userId) of User.

My thinking is right ?

If it's right, I have another Question.

When a User connect website it requires UserCertificate, Browser will show certificate List on what basis?
In my thinking, browser check that Request Url and CN is same.Is it right?
If so, I think Browser cannot select UserCertificates from all UserCertificates.Please teach me this is right or not

Comment: If I'm understanding the question right, I think the browser will only show you client certificates that are signed by one of a set of client-cert-CA certificates configured on the server.

Comment: thank you for answer.
Im sorry for my lack of knowledge.
what is exactly The sign of CA server, how I can see that?

Comment: If it's just for investigation, you can try connecting with openssl s_client - that prints a lot of useful information, especially in debug mode. I can't remember which field this is in or how to find it programatically sorry.